# Could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster - ELK Stack

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, fluentd

I am trying to deploy ELK Stack with FluentD, now facing Connectivity problem to Elastic from FluentD Containers. Please find details below

Problem:

```
logs to Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"localhost\", :port=>9200, :scheme=>\"https\", :user=>\"elastic\", :password=>\"obfuscated\"}): Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:9200 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)"
  2022-06-28 12:21:24 +0000 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
```

DockerFile:

```
RUN gem install fluent-plugin-elasticsearch
RUN gem install fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter
RUN gem install fluent-plugin-multi-format-parser
```

fluent.conf

```
  @type http
  port 9880
  bind 0.0.0.0
  body_size_limit 32m
  keepalive_timeout 10s
</source>


<match **>
        @type elasticsearch
        @log_level info
        include_tag_key true
        host localhost
        port 9200
        user elastic
        password WMvbcuMfTlSg_PDVInyZ
        ssl_verify false
        ssl_version TLSv1_2
        # ca_file /fluentd/etc/http_ca.crt
        # client_cert /fluentd/etc/http_ca.crt
        logstash_format true
        scheme https
        verify_es_version_at_startup false
        # default_elasticsearch_version 7
        request_timeout 59s
        # request_timeout 2147483648
        reload_connections false
        reconnect_on_error true
        reload_on_failure true
        with_transporter_log true
        <buffer>
         flush_interval 10s
        </buffer>
  </match>
```

to build image:

```
 docker build -t fluentd-app
```

to run the container:

```
docker run --name fluentd1 --net elastic -p 9880:9880 -d -v E:\fluentd_image\fluentd\conf:/fluentd/etc  fluentd-app
```

Answer (score 0):

ERRCONNREFUSED , means one of the following:

1. The ES server is off.
2. The ES server is not reachable due to a firewall issue.
3. You are using https, and hence will have to configure your SSL certificates and place them in the relevant folders.
4. You have bound to 0.0.0.0 but elasticsearch broadcast is different.

Please check the same and see if it fixes the issue. Please remember to mark this answer as correct if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
now I have downgraded Elastic Search to 7.16.3 which having no security check. Still facing same connectivity issues. i have checked all the four points which you mentioned. issue persist @brugia

Comment: Switch to http and dont use HTTPS and see if works, and let me know